# FLUTTER : get firestore value from all documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hello iam new to flutter and I want to get al the values from a specific field , here is my firestore :
[image]

there will be more than one document in orders , i want to get all the "total" fields , and sum them together for all orders , how can i do this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  There is plenty of documentation for reading documents from Firestore - start there if you don't have anything yet.

Comment: You need to get the collection "orders" and that's it... you can sort if you want with any variable you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all the documents first, then do your sum:

```
   final snapshots = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').get();
   final data = snapshots.docs.map((e) => e.data()['total']?.toDouble() ?? 0.0); 
   final sum = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: thanks alot , it seems that i have been using `.fold` and that's what cuz it to crash , thanks so much osama